# select link, automatically checks the checkbox to the left of it

Tags: jquery, html

I want to a user to be able to hover over a link, click it, and it will automatically check the checkbox to the left of it, and when they select it, it will uncheck the box.

How do I do this?

`<input type="checkbox" name="favorite_color" value="Orange"> <a href="#" rel="favorite_color">Orange</a>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of a link (anchor), use a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/label) which is designed for this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="favorite_color" id="favorite_color" value="Orange"> 
<label for="favorite_color">Orange</label>
```

Or without the `id`, wrapped around it:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="favorite_color" value="Orange"> Orange</label>
```

With both of these there's no JavaScript required, just built-in browser behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]')
  checkbox.attr('checked', checkbox.is(':checked'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="favorite_color" value="Orange">
<a href="#" rel="favorite_color" onclick="document.getElementById('chk').checked = true;"> Orange</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a link?  You could just underline/highlight a span inside a label.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_color" value="Orange">
    <span class="make_it_look_like_a_link">Orange</span>
</label>
```